# What's the difference between the 'DES' class and The 'DESCryptoServiceProvider' class?

Tags: c#, security, encryption

All I can make out is that one of them is the BC for all 'DES' algorithms to be derived from and the later is a wrapper for the Cryptographic service provider implementation of the DES algorithm.

The reason why I ask is that I am going over .Net Security and the MS official training book simply refers to the DES class but the another official MS book refers to the DESCrypto' class. What's the difference between these two? When would you use either of them? What do I need to know as far as the 70-536 exam is concerned.

I am asking my question from an educational P.O.V as far as the 70-536 exam is concerned.

Update:

Someone wanna shed some light on the IV property?

Comment: This is a lame exam talking about some obscure corner of an outdated technology.   DES is too small and no one should use 3DES when AES which is faster and more secure.

Comment: thanks for the comment, believe it or not, I have sat the paper already and failed by a very small margin. I did see this on the exam paper. So I have to read into but I hear you man !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the DES class is an abstract base class, DESCryptoServiceProvider is a concrete implementation for it.  The inheritance chain is a bit boring, it is the only one.

Most cryptography classes follow this pattern. It is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ss79b2x.aspx) as follows:

> The .NET Framework security system
>   implements an extensible pattern of
>   derived class inheritance. The
>   hierarchy is as follows:
>
> - Algorithm type class, such as SymmetricAlgorithm or HashAlgorithm.
>     This level is abstract.
> - Algorithm class that inherits from an algorithm type class; for example,
>     RC2 or SHA1. This level is abstract.
> - Implementation of an algorithm class that inherits from an algorithm
>     class; for example,
>     RC2CryptoServiceProvider or
>     SHA1Managed. This level is fully
>     implemented.
>
> Using this pattern of derived classes,
>   it is easy to add a new algorithm or a
>   new implementation of an existing
>   algorithm. For example, to create a
>   new public-key algorithm, you would
>   inherit from the AsymmetricAlgorithm
>   class. To create a new implementation
>   of a specific algorithm, you would
>   create a nonabstract derived class of
>   that algorithm.

Not so sure how often somebody actually adds a new public key algorithm.

Comment: +1 correct, although I always found it bizarre myself, are there actually `DES` implementations floating around other than the `DESCryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: The pluggability allows for alternate implementations, including hardware accelerated versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification: algorithm classes ending in CryptoServiceProvider are offloading the work to the built-in Windows crypto libraries; and those ending in Managed are written in C#.